# How to block user from commiting word documents in visualsvn

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, pre-commit-hook

Need help in writing pre-commit to hook in visual svn to block users from committing word documents in svn.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do that? We often submit documentation in formats like Word for our source code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the validate-files.py hook script that is included in the tools/hook-scripts directory of the Subversion 1.8.x tarball.  Alternatively you can just get the latest version from SVN in trunk (though I don't think it's changed):
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/validate-files.py

There is an example config file for it as well here:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/validate-files.conf.example

This is a basic framework for validating files.  You'll still need to provide a command that determines if a file is a word document.  If you want to reject a commit the command you configure should exit with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to prevent users from committing MS Office files to Subversion and VisualSVN Server. VisualSVN Server works great with Office files and its web interface now **supports viewing DOCX Word** files. Try this on the demo server at https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#documents.